# How to add a date in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm having two strings, **date** which has the **DateTime** which is converted to string, and another variable **days** which store the number of days (eg: 5), now what i have to do is that, I just want to add the **date** and **days** and the result should be in **DateTime** format.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PArse the Date and add the days(which should be double)

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(date).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(days));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse it to a datetime and add the days to the converted date,

```
  DateTime YourCurrentDate= DateTime.Parse(string s);
  DateTime endDate = YourCurrentDate.AddDays(addedDays);;
```

in single line,

```
 DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("string").AddDays(days);
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to parse your date string into datetime, and then add days:

```
var resultDate = DateTime.Parse("your date string").AddDays(days);
```